# Recursive function creating too many copies of child nodes

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm attempting to write a function to recursively delete nodes based on Parent-child relationships.

```
function recursiveDelete(parentNode, deleteStack) {

    let toDelete = allNodes.filter(function (node) {
      return node.Parent !== undefined && node.Parent[0] === parentNode.ID;
    })

    toDelete.forEach((childNode) => {
      deleteStack.push(...recursiveDelete(childNode, toDelete));
    });

  return deleteStack;
}
```

When I run this code, it create arrays with multiple copies of each node to be deleted, which seems to correspond to the height of the tree. It still seems to be running in polynomial time, but it isn't ideal.

edit - below is an example of what gets returned when I run the function on `allNodes`, with the duplicates.

```
[
    {
        "ID": "recymaQKcdrGzAqRM",
        "Name": "Depth 1",
        "Type": "task",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "6",
        "Parent": [
            "recQT9BPQtqs7Cg0U"
        ],
        "Predecessors": [
            "recKwlRnVhKik3SZF"
        ],
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "ID": "recRcn1t2Nkupcb9L",
        "Name": "Start",
        "Type": "start",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recymaQKcdrGzAqRM"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "recBmEBC1bo1CcJ8i",
        "Name": "Depth 2",
        "Type": "task",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recymaQKcdrGzAqRM"
        ],
        "Predecessors": [
            "recRcn1t2Nkupcb9L"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "recRcn1t2Nkupcb9L",
        "Name": "Start",
        "Type": "start",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recymaQKcdrGzAqRM"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "recBmEBC1bo1CcJ8i",
        "Name": "Depth 2",
        "Type": "task",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recymaQKcdrGzAqRM"
        ],
        "Predecessors": [
            "recRcn1t2Nkupcb9L"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "rec7qUgu7kpnQ06s7",
        "Name": "Start",
        "Type": "start",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recBmEBC1bo1CcJ8i"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "rec5Lyx3zuAsCPv9W",
        "Name": "Depth 3",
        "Type": "task",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recBmEBC1bo1CcJ8i"
        ],
        "Predecessors": [
            "rec7qUgu7kpnQ06s7"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "rec7qUgu7kpnQ06s7",
        "Name": "Start",
        "Type": "start",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recBmEBC1bo1CcJ8i"
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID": "rec5Lyx3zuAsCPv9W",
        "Name": "Depth 3",
        "Type": "task",
        "Duration": 0.1,
        "Priority": "5",
        "Parent": [
            "recBmEBC1bo1CcJ8i"
        ],
        "Predecessors": [
            "rec7qUgu7kpnQ06s7"
        ]
    }
]
```

My current hack is to just remove duplicates:

```
[...new Set(recursiveDelete(allNode, [allNode]))]
```

But I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

edit, I think I figured it out. Instead of passing `toDelete` to the recursive function, I should've only been passing `[childNode]`, so the correct code looks like this:

```
function recursiveDelete(parentNode, deleteStack) {
  let toDelete = allNodes.filter(function (node) {
    return node.Parent !== undefined && node.Parent[0] === parentNode.ID;
  });

  toDelete.forEach((childNode) => {
    deleteStack.push(...recursiveDelete(childNode, [childNode]));
  });

  return deleteStack;
}
```

Comment: You have some duplicate IDs in this tree. I noticed `recRcn1t2Nkupcb9L` for example. Is that expected? Because if not, it might be messing things up and picking duplicates it shouldn't.

Comment: I may have been unclear, that array is what gets returned, so those duplicates are the problem.

Comment: Right but is the data *correct* and nodes with duplicate IDs should be considered or is it just that the data is incorrect and the algorithm is correct as it is written?

Comment: I am confident the data is correct. When the height of the tree increases, the number of duplicate nodes increases, to the point where there can be more items in the array to delete than there are total items in the source array.